# How can you speed up the Highcharts network graph initial animation?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts 7.2.1 to create a network graph. It all works but it takes a long time for the nodes to settle in place. Is it possible to speed up the initial animation?
I can turn the animation off completely but that's not what I want to do.
I've tried setting the plotOptions.networkgraph.animation duration e.g.

```
plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            layoutAlgorithm: {
                enableSimulation: true,
                friction: -0.9,
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 10
            },
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work. Not even in the Highcharts jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0tv8fLer/
I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From source code: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/be75807e3323d890e69440b8306c011d35e5eb8e/ts/modules/networkgraph/networkgraph.src.ts#L828

> Animation in `networkgraph` is done through `requestAnimationFrame`
>   directly, without `Highcharts.animate()` use.

Positions of nodes are calculated on an ongoing basis and their position change is animated. Initially, we do not know what the final positions will be.

The only easy way to speed up the animation seems to be reducing `maxIterations`, `friction` or `maxSpeed` properties.

- with `verlet` integration: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qwf6xs2u/
- with `euler` integration: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uh34arb8/

---

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.layoutAlgorithm.friction

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.layoutAlgorithm.maxIterations

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/network-graph